# What is the difference between Root Class & Base Class in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Recently I faced a question in a exam, **"What are the Root Class in Objective-C?"** and I got two class as root class in `Objective-C`

**a)** NSProxy
**b)** NSObject.

What is the difference between a Root Class & Base Class in `Objective-C`?

Comment: Note that you can create additional root classes with `NS_ROOT_CLASS`.

Answer (score 5):

"Base class" is usually interchangeable with "superclass" (the normal ObjC terminology) when talking about a particular object's design and inheritance.

A root class in ObjC is a class which has no superclass; it is the ultimate base class from which other classes are typically derived. The standard root class for almost all objects in the Cocoa frameworks is `NSObject`, although there are others.

Answer (score 1):

> A root class inherits from no other class and defines an interface and
>   behavior common to all objects in the hierarchy below it. All objects
>   in that hierarchy ultimately inherit from the root class. A root class
>   is sometimes referred to as a base class.

[Apple Doc for RootClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/RootClass.html)